# how to call function inside other function in angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services, nested-function

**Example**
`
function1(){

------- this is main function

```
function2(){

  ------this is child function
```

}

}

`

**i need to call function2 in typescript**

Comment: Where do you need to call the function from?

Comment: i need to call function2() from function1()

Comment: In that case, you can just invoke `function2()` directly inside `function1()`. What is the problem you are running into?

Comment: actually i wrote a method inside another method in angular service. so, now i need to call that inside method in component

Comment: That seems much more complicated than your initial question as written; please edit to include more details closer to your actual usecase.

Comment: formats the code correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Define the child function outside of the main function. Call the child function to multiple places as your need.

Of course, you need that to be called in `function1()` and call any other places as you like.

```
function1(){
   this.function2();  
}

function2(){

}
```